# Why unique_ptr with custom deleter won't work for nullptr, while shared_ptr does?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, language-lawyer

Simple code to use either `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` as a scope guard. All information about what to clear is captured in the `deleter`, so I though it is safe to use `nullptr` for constructor.

Apparently, with Visual C++ 2017 (14.1), it is not working as expected for `unique_ptr`, but works for `shared_ptr`. Is it a Microsoft quirk, or does the standard prevent calling the `deleter` of a `unique_ptr` when holding `nullptr`?

In the code below, I'm forced to construct a `unique_ptr` with `(void*)1`. If I construct it with `nullptr`, `cleaner` won't be called. For `shared_ptr`, there is no difference, `cleaner` is always called.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int ttt = 77;

    auto cleaner = [&ttt](void*) {
        std::cout << "cleaner: " << ttt << "\n"; // do something with capture here instead of print
    };

    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(cleaner)> p((void*)1, cleaner);

    std::shared_ptr<void> q(nullptr, [&ttt](void*) {
        std::cout << "shared: " << ttt << "\n"; // do something with capture here instead of print
    });

    std::cout << "done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KillzoneKid as I said, please replace `(void*)1` with `nullptr` and try again.

Comment: No need to construct an invalid pointer with `(void*)1`, just use `&p`.

Comment: May be worth looking at [gsl::finally](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_util) which is part of the [Guideline Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) which is implementing the recommendations from the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) (Stroustrup & Sutter).

Comment: @Barry: That's not actually what the Standard says.  `shared_ptr` default constructor will create an empty shared_ptr.  So will copying or moving an empty shared_ptr, and move leaves the old shared_ptr empty.  But it doesn't say that construction with a `nullptr` results in an empty shared_ptr; on the contrary it guarantees that `use_count() == 1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`unique_ptr`'s destructor is required to do so:

> **23.11.1.2.2 unique_ptr destructor [unique.ptr.single.dtor]**
>
> 2 Effects: If `get() == nullptr` there are no effects. Otherwise `get_deleter()(get())`.

actually `shared_ptr`'s destructor is required to do the same:

> **23.11.2.2.2 shared_ptr destructor [util.smartptr.shared.dest]**
>
> — (1.1) If `*this` is empty or shares ownership with another `shared_ptr` instance ( `use_count() > 1` ), there are no side effects.
>
> — (1.2) Otherwise, if `*this` owns an object p and a deleter d, d(p) is called.

So relying on smart pointers to perform arbitrary actions at scope exit while passing null pointers is not reliable.

Comment: And this required me write my own wrapper (wanted to use unique_ptr) to wrap some MS-Window's handles. Where -1 is used for invalid handle and 0 is a valid handle that needs to be cleaned up.  It's a shame as calling delete on nullptr is defined to have no effect anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's rather unfortunate that nullptr no-op is part of `unique_ptr` -- it should have been made part of the default deleter.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, that would be better

Comment: @RichardCritten Which handles use 0 as a valid handle value? Even when some APIs return something like `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (in case of `CreateFile` for example), 0 is still an invalid value that does not require cleanup.

Comment: Where do you find that 0 is not a valid handle?  I have always assumed that all values except `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` were possible.

Comment: No, `shared_ptr` does invoke the deleter.

Comment: @BenVoigt Neither holds, in fact. You can construct an empty `shared_ptr` whose `get()` returns a non-null pointer (via the aliasing constructor).

Comment: @T.C.: Ah, by passing in an empty shared_ptr?  The Standard has a note that this constructor can make an empty shared_ptr but it doesn't say under what conditions that happens.

Comment: @RichardCritten 0 is not a valid handle because it otherwise it could not be closed by `CloseHandle` function which explicitly requires argument to be a non-null value. Actually attempt to do so causes `warning C6387: 'handle' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'CloseHandle'`. Also see [Why are HANDLE return values so inconsistent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040302-00/?p=40443/).

Comment: @VTT: Not all Win32 "handles" are meant to be passed to `CloseHandle`.  For example, some are freed by `DeleteObject` or `DestroyWindow`.  (Feel free to argue that Microsoft should not have called these by the same moniker as kernel handles... but they did)

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, there are definitely many types of handles, but I can't name any handle type that uses 0 as a valid handle value.

Comment: @VTT: I think that's true, but you can't reach that conclusion starting from the preconditions of `CloseHandle`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I only reached the conclusion that 0 is not a valid value for a handle returned by `CreateFile` even though it does not return 0 to indicate an error.

Comment: @VTT Here's one `FindFirstFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` but should not closed by `CloseHandle`, instead it need to be closed by `FindClose`.  My thinking is that: if there's one there might be more.  As the link you posted said, it's a bit of a mess for historical reasons so I feel safer when writing wrappers to assume in some cases 0 might be valid.

Comment: @RichardCritten Again, 0 is not a valid value for a handle returned by `FindFirstFile` because this value is not valid for `FindNextFile` or `FindClose` calls.

Comment: @VTT can you give me a link to the pre-condition information, as a simple search of MSDN is only returning this sort of page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx  on which I can't see the pre-condition you mention.

Comment: Note that I solve the "Win32 handle in a ``unique_ptr``" issue with a helper which makes sure that ``INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`` is converted to 0 so I end up with ``ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(CreateFile2(...)))``. See [scoped.h](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/master/DirectXTex/scoped.h) and [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/master/DirectXTex/DirectXTexDDS.cpp) for some example usage.

Comment: @RichardCritten Precondition is written as SAL annotation for function parameter `_In_ HANDLE hFindFile`. Pasing 0 should yield a warning when compiled in visual studio.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr
Unlike std::unique_ptr, the deleter of std::shared_ptr is invoked even if the managed pointer is null.